# Expo, React Native force Portrait mode on iPadOS

Tags: react-native, expo

i would like to ask if there is any working way to force iPadOS to PORTRAIT mode, it doesnt work because iPad has "split view"

based on Expo screen orientation plugin

- https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/

there is warrning but without any FIX for that

Apple added support for split view mode to iPads in iOS 9. This changed how the screen orientation is handled by the system

my app.json

```json
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    ...
}
```